# How do I block access to a windows share on a host?

Tags: networking, windows-7

I have a windows share that anyone can connect to (no password), however users of specific computers should not be allowed to connect to them. How do I disable access for those users on those computers?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to set a password for the allowed computers.

Else, if the computers that you don't like to share the resource have static IP and they don't need to connect to the sharing computer, you can block their IP in the host files to prevent their access:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5422923_block-ip-address-computer.html

But this alternative is less secure than adding a password.

Comment: this method will not work. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) it will work if you have a hostname to use (as in the example from the link you provided), but that's only because it will attempt to give itself the same host name and then connect back to itself (not finding a webserver on 127.0.0.1 and displaying that the page could not be loaded). at best the method you propose is a hack.